# Как сохранить в базу данные из списка с множественным выбором в yii2?

Tags: yii2

В форме есть dropDownList для вывода данных из базы в виде выпадающего списка с множественным выбором:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'parts[]')->dropDownList($model->IngredientDropdown, ['multiple' => 'multiple'] ); ?>
```

В модели:

```
public function getIngredientDropdown()
{
    $listIngredient = Ingredient::find()->select('id,ititle')->all();
    $list = ArrayHelper::map( $listIngredient, 'id', 'ititle');
    return $list;

}
```

В контроллере:

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Dish();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Прошу подсказать как  сохранить в базу в поле parts выделенные в select данные в виде одной записи через запятую?

Answer (score 1):

Просто перед сохранением нужно преобразовать массив в строку, сделать это можно функцией [implode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php)

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Dish();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->parts = implode(',', $model->parts);
        if ($model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Перед выводом в форму для редактирования модели, необходимо наоборот преобразовать строку в массив с помощью функции [explode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)

```
public function actionUpdate()
{
    $model = Dish::findOne($id); 
    $model->parts = explode(',', $model->parts);        

    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
    {
        $model->parts = implode(',', $model->parts);    
            if ($model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```